# needed: .php file causing browser to download folder & all its contents w/out archiving

Tags: php, browser, download, directory, subdirectory

I wish I had a .php file that, when linked to, causes all commonly used browsers in all commonly used operating systems to download a folder and all of its contents, including its subfolders and the files in them (especially image files such as .jpg and .tif). For example: a .php file that causes the download of any folder (folder x, folder g, folder d, etc.) that I place it next to on my server: I would like the .php file to do this without being rewritten each time I use it to indicate which folder it points at. I would like its location to do the pointing so as to avoid rewriting. So, for example, the .ph'could cause the download of any folder it sits next to on my server. Or it could cause the download of the folder in which it sits, although that would unfortunately probably entail causing itself to be downloaded.

I would like this to work so that I could, for example, (using ftp) just put files (and folders and subfolders with other files in them) in folder x on my server, and then put folder x and this .php file inside folder y, and then link one person to the .php file with the result that, when they click on the link, their browser opens a save dialog giving them the chance to choose a location for folder x and all its contents to be saved to. Or, even better, when they click on the link, their browser simply starts downloading folder x and all its contents to their drive without opening a save dialog. Without zipping or other archiving on the fly: just downloading folder x and all its contents as is.

I'm (obvioulsy, by now!) not a programmer--not even close. I have never written code or script or etc.; I don't know how to write php. I know how to save text in a text editor as a .php file and then place that file on my server via ftp, and that's about it. If my ignorance makes this an inappropriate request, then I apologize in advance.

Humbly,

Mark

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Web browsers can only download files, not folders -- you will need to use some form of archiving.

Comment: Ahhh--I see. Okay, I'll hope for a script that does it with archiving, then.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example here.

http://www.travisberry.com/2010/09/use-php-to-zip-folders-for-download/

ZIP archives would be much cleaner than the way you are explaining.

Comment: Ahhh--I see.

Okay, I'll hope for a script that does it with archiving, then.
But Zip archiving always fails for me and my friends using Mac OS X: when I archive .tifs and upload them for friends, and when they download them, they always are unable to uncompress. I, too, am unable to uncompress after I download the very files that I zipped and uploaded. Is there some other form of archiving that would work, and that would work with this kind of .php file? It's always just .tifs and .jpgs that I upload. If so, could someone please give me the .php file that works this way?

With thanks,

Mark

Comment: Yes, I saw the travisberry script before. Thank you, though. I opted to try the simpler version he refers to: http://www.trash.net/~ck/ontheflyzip/  ; the downloading part of it worked well, as would the travisberry script, I'm sure, but the zips are always uncompressible for me and my friends using osx. And I need for it to work for clients of mine who won't put up with downloading alternative uncompressers...

Comment: this is the trouble I get with zip files:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1446784?start=0&tstart=0